# Installing Nagios plugins on Centreon

Tags: plugins, centos, monitoring, nagios

I am very new to monitoring and with linux.
So i took the easy path and Installed FullyAutomatedNagios (FAN) on a linux machine (CentOS).
and installed/configured NSclient++ on windows machine i wanted to monitor. Via webinterfece of FAN which is centreon i started to monitor basic parameters like (memory,cpu,disks,services etc) Via CHECK_NT commands. 
Now i want to move forward and want to monitor something more like DB performance,queries etc , but inorder to do that i need to install nagios plugins and i have no idea how can i do that.please help.

Comment: Read the (not FAN) Nagios core docs at: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/4/en/toc.html

Answer (score 0):

The first things to do in my opinion are :

- Know exactly what do you want to check (DB, Web server, ...)
- Search on http://exchange.nagios.org/ or others (why not) if there are already some plugins who responding to your demand.
- Search if the check can be done directly on the monitoring server or in the client server (the protocol will change, NRPE, NSClient++ or SNMP for example)
- If yes, you have to implement them on your monitoring server, on your plugins directory (where are your CPU, memory plugins) and execute the script with corrects parameters if the plugin works.
- If yes, you can now implement them on your interface and make them automatic, like create command, create service...

Define your metrics and check when you want your plugins output Warning alert or Critical alert and all these things are set in the interface.

If you don't find plugins, you must create one.

This is way to do and can be optimized obviously.

Nicolas B.